# Upload of Image in SAPUI5 without FileUploader

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Is it possible to upload a file to SAP GW by using the `create`-method of ODataModel?

I send the Image as a Base64-String to backend. In backend the create-stream method is executed and in parameter `is_media_resource` the value is filled. Now I call a function module to save the image to a order.

But when I look into the order attachments, I can choose the Image but it shows nothing.

*Additional my code:*

```js
oModel.create(
    sPath, {
      value: oEvent.detail.base64
    }, 
    {
      headers: {
        slug: oEvent.detail.filename
      },
      success: function (oData, oResponse) {
        var aPhotolist = oListsModel.getProperty("/photoList");

        aPhotolist.results.push(oData);
        oListsModel.setProperty("/photoList", aPhotolist);
        oCarousel.getBinding("pages").refresh();
        oDialog.close();
        sap.m.MessageToast.show(JSON.parse(oResponse.headers["sap-message"]).message, {
          closeOnBrowserNavigation: false
        });
      },
      error: function (oError) {
        MessageBox.error(JSON.parse(oError.responseText).error.message.value);
        oDialog.close();
      }
    }
);
```

Comment: You can use [sap.m.UploadCollection](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.UploadCollection)

Comment: The upload should start after the picture has been taken by camera. Is it possible to use the UploadCollection only in js? I won't no UploadCollection displayed on the view.

Comment: Yes you can use the `UploadCollection` in js file. But it will not support the camera functionality. In `UploadCollection` file has to browser and file upload will take care by the `UploadCollection`. Better you can use `ajax` call. After the camera image is saved in your local, get the path and get the file binary data and make a `ajax` call. [Attachment Upload in SAPUI5 application through Gateway](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3670662)

Answer (score 1):

Now I found a solution:

```
    var sPath = this.getBindingContext().getPath() + "/ToAttachments",
            oListsModel = this.getModel("listsModel"),
            oCarousel = this,
            imgData = JSON.stringify(oEvent.detail.base64);

        oCarousel.setBusy(true);
        this.getBindingContext().getModel().create(
            sPath,
            imgData, {
                headers: {
                    slug: oEvent.detail.filename
                },
                success: function (oData, oResponse) {
                    var aPhotolist = oListsModel.getProperty("/photoList");

                    aPhotolist.results.push(oData);
                    oListsModel.setProperty("/photoList", aPhotolist);
                    oCarousel.getBinding("pages").refresh();
                    oCarousel.setBusy(false);
                    sap.m.MessageToast.show(JSON.parse(oResponse.headers["sap-message"]).message, {
                        closeOnBrowserNavigation: false
                    });
                },
                error: function (oError) {
                    oCarousel.setBusy(false);
                    MessageBox.error(JSON.parse(oError.responseText).error.message.value);
                }
            });
```

First you have to convert the data of the image to a string.

In backend take the value from parameter `is_media_resource` and convert it first back from xstring to string.

```
lf_data = is_media_resource-value.

lo_conv_x2c = cl_abap_conv_in_ce=>create( ).

lo_conv_x2c->convert( EXPORTING input = lf_data

                      IMPORTING data  = base64_string ).
```

After that, convert the string again into xstring. This is now a xstring, which can be interpreted by SAP

```
CALL FUNCTION 'SSFC_BASE64_DECODE'
  EXPORTING
    b64data                  = base64_string
  IMPORTING
    bindata                  = lf_data
  EXCEPTIONS
    ssf_krn_error            = 1
    ssf_krn_noop             = 2
    ssf_krn_nomemory         = 3
    ssf_krn_opinv            = 4
    ssf_krn_input_data_error = 5
    ssf_krn_invalid_par      = 6
    ssf_krn_invalid_parlen   = 7
    OTHERS                   = 8.
```

It seems, SAP has some problem to interpret the base64 string vom Javascript.